# How to "change" input type file style

Tags: javascript, html, css

**(Read down the edit)**

So I have been trying to do this a lot and I can't figure it out.

FIRST: the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2RHfL/

What I want to do is to "change" the style of a input type="file". So what I did was to set it's opacity: 0 and then try to make it so that if fits entirely his parent div, so that when the user clicks at any part of the parent div, the input will be clicked (I can't do this via javascript, because I also want the user to drag & drop files to input). I can't change the input to an upload manager though javascript, I must do this trough the input tag.

I know the css is a little big, but the important stuff are the last two rules only, that modify the input & form css style:

```
.ux-hotels-reviews-upload .formAddDoc {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ux-hotels-reviews-upload .formAddDoc .inputFile {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
 /* font-size: 10000px;
  border: 10000px solid transparent;
  right: -1000px;
  top: -1000px;*/
}
```

So, what I want is: If the user clicks/drops a file at the parent div (.ux-hotels-reviews-upload) make the click/drop to the input, but the input has to have his opacity to 0 and the items inside the div should look as they do now. (You can see that the opacity:0 rule is commented just for testing reasons).

If I forgot to mention something, tell me.

**EDIT:
I've made a new fiddle so that it is more readble and easy to understand my problem, also I think I am a bit closer to the solution:**

http://jsfiddle.net/fLfce/

So as you can see, if the FORM is with position: relative, then if fits perfectly the div (what I want) but the thext goes out of the div, si if I put position: absolute to the form, then the text goes exactly where I want but the FORM gets bigger (much more than the div).
What I want is: The form to be position: absolute and keep it's width and height to the 100% of the div, not more, not less.

```
        form {
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        input {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do then you have to use negative margins with positive padding and a `z-index` on the `.ux-hotels-reviews-upload .formAddDoc .inputFile` file.

Like this:

```
.ux-hotels-reviews-upload .formAddDoc .inputFile {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: -30%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 31%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

You need to 'fine-tune' the margin and padding to fit the div container.

Comment: I don't get it, just tried it and the input goes to the right half of the div

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2RHfL/5/
Border is a bit off, but the effect that you wanted is there. Your HTML & CSS was very hard to read & messy, I suggest going through some refactoring.

```
input[type=file]{
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but this only works if the div is at the top of the page, when it is not, then the form keeps staying at the top of the page :(

Comment: Then move it down/up using `top` and `bottom`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is wrap the area you want to show as a label, pointing to the file input, like this:

```
<label for="uploadPictureInput">
```

This will activate the file input when you interact with it (you could even replace your "ux-hotels-reviews-upload-info" div with it).

Though I think you still have to use javascript for drag&drop to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display:none"/>
<div onclick="file.click()" ondragdrop="file.dragdrop()">Text</div>
```

The `<div>` acts like the parent div that you mentionned but doesn't contain the file input which isn't displayed because of `style="display:none"`.